# How to access client user's webcam remotely using silverlight

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I want to to be able to use client webcam and microphone using `Silverlight`. I'm searching a solution to this for months now but I did not find any relevant information.

What's the requirements needed to access the user webcam, and How should I start?
and let me know is there any possible to access client user's webcam with any other technologies?

Comment: What you tried so far?? provide some sample code..

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of "How should I start?" You should read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602282(v=vs.95).aspx).

The answer to your other question is yes. There are many different client-server setups to interact with the client's webcam. It comes down to personal preference as to which one you want to use.